# Magento 2.3.1 unserialize error

Tags: error, magento2.3, php-7.2, unserialize

In magento 2.3.1 I have this code:

```
public function encrypt($params)
    {
        return base64_encode($this->encryptor->encrypt(serialize($params)));
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt tracking key
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @return array
     */
    public function decrypt($key)
    {
        $serializedParams = $this->encryptor->decrypt(base64_decode($key));
        return unserialize($serializedParams);
    }
```

It is from a module which tracks newsletters. But I get error

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 48 bytes in myfile.php on
>   line 51

Which is

```
return unserialize($serializedParams);
```

Can anyone help me with the right syntax of this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go here and change the code as per the below instruction.

```
public function encrypt($params)
    {
        return base64_encode($this->encryptor->encrypt(json_encode($params))); 
    }
/**
 * Decrypt tracking key
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @return array
 */
public function decrypt($key)
{
    $serializedParams = $this->encryptor->decrypt(base64_decode($key));
    return json_decode($serializedParams,true); 
}
```

3. Please run the below command

```
 php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: The answer is wrong. Probably you mean to use **\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json** class in myfile.php

Comment: no, I have already mentioned the file above. you can just change $value = $this->serialize->unserialize($serializeData); in __custruct method

Comment: In **\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\** folder there is Json.php file and the code there isn't the one you mention

Comment: the file is available here *vendor\magento\framework\Serialize\Serializer/Json*

Comment: I found the file but it doesn't have the code you mention

Comment: you used the magento 2.3.1 that file is already change

Comment: The problem I think is on myfile.php and not in Magento

Comment: yes, u can used serialize and unserialize instance of json_encode and decode in your code

Comment: I have updated the answer check my new answer

Comment: Thank you! Solved!